# I have this error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:Application:assembleDebug]
:Application:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Application:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Application:checkDebugManifest
:Application:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72330Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132330Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42330Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareDebugDependencies
:Application:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:Application:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:Application:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:Application:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:Application:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:Application:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:Application:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:Application:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:Application:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:Application:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:Application:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:Application:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:Application:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:Application:compileDebugSources
:Application:prePackageMarkerForDebug
:Application:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main :         Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error:  at     java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error:  at     sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:Exception in thread "main" 
Error:Execution failed for task         ':Application:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
    > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:     java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program             Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2.159 secs
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main :     Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error:  at     java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main :     Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error:  at    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error:  at     sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
Error:Exception in thread "main" 
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error:  at    sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:Exception in thread "main" 
Information:46 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I imported a sample code in android it's called "Camera2Basic"
but i renamed it to CameraSampleApp and so after the build is done i tried running it and this error pops up. am i doing something wrong or my Android Studio is outdated.

Comment: Does it work if you don't rename it?

Comment: Clean and rebuild try it

Comment: @TimCastelijns i tried  not renaming it and import it as it is it still has this kind of error

Comment: @AdityaVyas how to clean and rebuild i'm new to android studio actually.

Comment: just click Build>Clean Project

Comment: Done doing it and this this some errors still comes>

Answer (score 1):

The *smart* way to fix that problem is to compile using the latest SDK and use the [cross compilation options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCJDCID) when compiling.  To use the options *completely correctly* requires the `rt.jar` of a JRE (**not JDK**) of the target version.

Given the nature of that applet, it looks like it could be compiled for use with Java 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest add multiDexEnabled true to your build.gradle file

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: i can't post it in the comments because its too long . can i message it to you

Answer (score 0):

uninstall the old jdk and install the latest jdk(1.8) and change the environment  variable path of JAVA_HOME to latest jdk. In android studio change the java path to latest jdk.